# Error 403 to send mail sendgrid via firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I cannot send an email from a firebase function as soon as it detects a write on my database.

- I checked the key api and mail that I entered using the command `firebase functions:config:set`
- I checked that my key was indeed on "full access"
- I authenticated my account (mail...) and the dns parameters
- I authorized all access for all users in my function on google cloud and I even set my realtime database writing and reading rules to true.

Despite all this, I always get a 403 error on my console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Of course my application is initialized and deployed correctly,
I ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` and checked the sendgrid dependencies in my package.json folder.

I even added in firebase.json:`

```
"functions": [
{
  "sendEmail": {
    "allow": "true"
  },`
```

my code :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

// Configure SendGrid with your API key
const sendgridApiKey = functions.config().sendgrid.api_key;
sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridApiKey);

export const sendEmail = functions.database
  .ref('{Client}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    try {
      const writeData = snapshot.val();

      // Retrieve necessary information from the database
      const fromEmail = functions.config().sendgrid.sender_email;
      const toEmail = writeData.email;
      const message = writeData.message;

      const msg = {
        to: toEmail,
        from: fromEmail,
        subject: 'Nouvelle écriture détectée dans la base de données',
        text: `Un nouvel enregistrement a été ajouté à la base de données : ${message}`,
        html: `Un nouvel enregistrement a été ajouté à la base de données : ${message}`,
        templateId: functions.config().sendgrid.sender_templates,
      };

      // Send the email via SendGrid
      await sgMail.send(msg);

      console.log('E-mail envoyé avec succès !');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'e-mail :', error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your Cloud Function code but I can see two potential problems:

1. You are mixing JavaScript `require()` and `import()` statements. You should do as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
```

2. You don't return a Promise (or a value) in order to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that all the asynchronous work (i.e. `sgMail.send()`) has completed. More detail on this key point in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?hl=en).

```
export const sendEmail = functions.database
  .ref('{Client}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    try {
      const writeData = snapshot.val();

      // Retrieve necessary information from the database
      const fromEmail = functions.config().sendgrid.sender_email;
      const toEmail = writeData.email;
      const message = writeData.message;

      const msg = {
        to: toEmail,
        from: fromEmail,
        subject: 'Nouvelle écriture détectée dans la base de données',
        text: `Un nouvel enregistrement a été ajouté à la base de données : ${message}`,
        html: `Un nouvel enregistrement a été ajouté à la base de données : ${message}`,
        templateId: functions.config().sendgrid.sender_templates,
      };

      // Send the email via SendGrid
      await sgMail.send(msg);

      console.log('E-mail envoyé avec succès !');

      return true;  <==== See addition here

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'e-mail :', error);

      return true;  <==== See addition here
    }
  });
```

---

I would also try without the `templateId` option just to check if this could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made the changes you recommended including removing the template but the problem persists and always sends me this authentication error in my console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()